# why isn't my javascript .replace() working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove any character except 0-9 a-z A-Z....

```
var file_name = file.name;
file_name = file_name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9\._\-]/i, '');
```

any obvious reason the above isn't working?

Comment: You should show some input and output data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the global-flag on your regular expression. Otherwise, only the first occurrence will be replaced:

```
file_name = file_name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9\._\-]/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) a go. Hover over the check boxes under the text box at the top to see the options you have. Look at the bottom pane to see the generated Regex.